# can %in% be used as an intersection in R

Tags: r, intersection

I have two data.frames and I need to take an intersection. With all the options available can `%in%` be used as an intersection in order to retrieve common variables? e.g

```
df1 <- c("gene1","gene2","gene5","gene7")
df2 <- c("gene3","gene4","gene5","gene1")

int <- which(df1%in%df2)

int
[1] 1 3
```

I am pretty sure I have answered my own question but I sort of feel like I am forcing it to be the answer rather than it being the actual answer.

Comment: What you present is not a data.frame. `%in%` is another name for `match`, which will see if elements on the right side appear in the object on the left side of the function.

Comment: `intersect(df1, df2)` Or if it is a data.frame, `library(dplyr);inner_join(df1, df2)` assuming that the column names are the same.

Comment: if you want to use only `%in%` and `which` functions, you can use `df2[which(df2 %in% df1[which(df1%in%df2)])]`